# Creating a self-signed certificate from the keypair on the smartcard

Tags: openssl, smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc

I generated a keypair on the smartcard using pkcs11-tool from OpenSC and the custom PKCS#11 library. This PKCS#11 library is my test object.

Now I want to create a certificate out of this keypair.
So far I found the way to create certificate when I have keypair in PEM format (file), but I want to use keypair on the card.

I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639). You will still need the commands to access the smartcard.